# modify fridge to temporarily defeat auto-defrost?

Tags: appliances

I would like to modify my 3 year-old KitchenAid KRFC300ESS french-door (freezer on bottom) refrigerator to disable the auto-defrost cycle on a short-term basis, preferably by putting in a switch mounted near the front (ideally, connected the low-voltage control circuitry, not the defrost heater itself).

The motivation is that I'd like to be able to drive a few critical loads from a 1kW inverter, during short-term (few days) power outages.  The inverter is usually able to handle these with aplomb, but during a recent power outage it could not (overloads and shuts off) even when I isolated so the fridge was the only load.  I believe the auto-defrost must be the culprit.

I am a EE, and I'm comfortable going inside of appliances (in fact, I fixed a noise problem on this fridge that a tech could or would not).   But I don't have the first clue how auto-defrost works, in theory or in practice.

Comment: This video talks about testing the continuity of a thermostat (it's short but extremely basic): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zmdsBkO46dk&feature=youtu.be.   Wondering if it's as simple as interrupting the path to the thermostat, probably low current and voltage ?

Comment: This (from applianceblog-dot-com) makes it sound a bit more complex though: Adaptive defrost- The control uses information from the thermistors and keeps track of number of door openings, compressor run time and length of time the defrost heater was energized during the last defrost cycle to know when to start the next defrost cycle. That can be anywhere between 9 and 99 hours

Comment: [Here](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/whirlpool-heater-w10825088-ap5985212.html) is what your defrost heater looks like.  You can search the other parts diagrams for the fridge to see if you can find what the heater hooks up to.

Comment: Why do you believe the heater is the problem? I would guess the start current of the compressor would be a bigger problem. Starting current for motors can easily be 3-4 times nominal current. This may be enough to trip a 1kW inverter...

Comment: Because the first time I messed with my inverter rig powering these essential house loads, the refrigerator compressor cycled several times with no problems.  And that was with a few other minor loads connected - 80 watts of LED lights, modem/router/phone, 120vac circuits on range (so gas would flow).   This time I isolated fridge by itself.   Also, I've measured the steady-state of the fridge at 100+ watts; so even 4x that should not trip the inverter, especially with the fridge by itself.   Furthermore, the inverter claims to have 2000watt surge capacity.

Comment: Defeat, Not bypass, temporarily disable, circumvent, sidestep, or render incapable but **Defeat !** Yea, even vanquish thee O Auto-Defrost.

Comment: Can't find "laugh" icon.  Ok, ok - temporarily disable.

Answer (score 1):

Auto-defrost just raises the temperature enough that the accumulated undesired ice build up (very thin at this point) melts away while still cold enough and short term enough to not melt the items frozen in the freezer. It does this with a heater inside the fridge to periodically warm the appliance during the defrost cycle. [Here's a video that explains it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qIFuWc0dAIw)

If you want to disable, you can find and remove or cut the wire to the heater. There should be a wiring diagram on the back and probably down low. Due to your background, I think that you can take it from here

Comment: Thanks.   Seems like it'd be better to disable the control of it though (e.g. by interrupting the thermostat), as I imagine the heater wires would have higher voltage and/or current.

Comment: ? I don't think that the thermostat has anything to do with the defrost cycle. It's going to either be purely timer based or based on how often you open and close the freezer.

Comment: But the video (I linked in the first comment to my OP) refers to the "defrost thermostat".

Comment: I didn't see your comments, probably best to add to the question by editing. Ok, you've help expand my mind too, and I now see that -some- freezers have defrost thermometers,  From what I've researched, there can be a thermostat but it is to keep it from getting too cold. Per this site acmehowto.com/howto/appliance/refrigerator/check/defrosthermo.php "The defrost thermostat is located near the defrost heater and is wired in series." There is also a video linked in the description of the video you referenced. In next note, too little space here

Comment: Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shFGqflIHtc

Comment: Another comment to post an idea I just had. I suggest inserting a switch on a low voltage part of the circuit that you are going to modify so that you can turn it on and off again without opening things back up again.

Comment: Oh yes, that. exactly what I intend to do.  Sounds like I need to edit OP for clarity :-)

Comment: I see your update; I'm not entirely clear on your question but I think I have answered them? or is there something that I expand on?

Comment: Where is the defrost thermostat located ?

Comment: Probably in the same compartment with the light, if you have one in your freezer, or behind an obvious panel

Answer (score 1):

At the rear of the freezer compartment there is a plastic cover held on with 4 screws. Behind that I should find the evaporator coils, and the defrost heater will be attached to that.  If I add a small SPST switch in series with the heater, thing will function normally when the switch is closed.   If I open the switch, the heater cannot operate.

During power outages when I'm trying to power essential house loads with the 1kW inverter, I'll open that switch.  Seems like the worst that can happen is that the evaporator coils ice up; I can help that not to happen by avoiding door openings.   But if it does happen, I'm no worse off than in the olden days before auto-defrost.  I'd have to unplug the thing for awhile (perhaps a day) and let the coils defrost.  Also, it appears the heater runs off 120vac, so I need to be careful with the way the switch is wired and mounted.

Comment: To have the switch operate at low voltage, I'd have to get into the control circuitry in the rear of the unit.  Cpmplicated, and there no reason I shouldn't be able to make the simpler line-voltage solution safe.

Comment: I think the best thing to do is to open up the back of the freezer compartment, as stated above, and interrupt the wire to the defrost heater with a "normally closed" relay (or a SPDT one, using the correct terminals to make it behave as NC).  Then just bring the coil wires out of the rear compartment, perhaps to a 9v-battery connector, so I just plug in a 9v battery when I'm running the fridge off the small inverter.   This way, I'm not bringing any dangerous wires out of the rear compartment.

Comment: This relay(the G5LE-14) looks good: https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/307/en_g5le-1131193.pdf . Note it is "fully sealed" so hopefully will be happy in the moist & cold environment of the freezer compartment (presumably the 85% RH% max rating applies only to the un-sealed version)\.   The 10amp resistive-load spec should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the thermostat, my GE frig monitors air temp leaving the evaporator coil and the temperature rise that occurs when the ice is gone indicates the defrost cycle can end. I learned there is also a defrost cycle on power-up before the compressor will kick in. It's annoying when you're in a hurry to see the compressor run but goes fast if there's no ice present.

My idea is to interrupt the 12v going to the defrost relay. It's a bit trickier than putting a switch in line with the heating element, but a wider variety of switches and lighter gauge wire would get it done. I may even use an opto-isolater.

Comment: If you look at the schematic I put in a related question, I don't believe there is a relay for the defroster ... https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/205329/help-me-understand-this-fridge-auto-defrost-circuit